# Showing " Notice: Undefined variable:" and " Notice: Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: wordpress

I have used feature image to a custom post. I have wrote the following code to use that feature image to my plugin.

```
 while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();

    $newsbox_post_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '', false, '' );

    $list .= '<li class="news-item">
    <table cellpadding="4">
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <img src="'.$newsbox_post_img_src[0].'" width="100" class="img-circle" />
           </td>
           <td>'.get_the_excerpt().'</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        </li>';

 endwhile;
```

But it is showing

> Undefined variable...

and

> Trying to get property of non-object....

notices.

[image: Error images]

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `$post->ID` when inside the loop. Also, you will need to actually check if `$newsbox_post_img_src` has something to return, otherwise it will return a

> Trying to get property of non-object

error.

Your code should basically look something like this

```
while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();   
    $newsbox_post_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), '', false, '' );

    $list = '<li class="news-item">';
    $list .= '<table cellpadding="4">';
    $list .= '<tr>';
    $list .= '<td>';
    if( !empty($newsbox_post_img_src)) {
        $list .= '<img src="'.$newsbox_post_img_src[0].'" width="100" class="img-circle" />';
    }       
    $list .= '</td>';
    $list .= '<td>'.get_the_excerpt().'</td>';
    $list .= '</tr>';
    $list .= '</table>';
    $list .= '</li>';
    echo $list;

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Would you please explain why `$post->ID` doesn't need? @Pieter Goosen

Comment: When in the loop, by default, the current post ID is used. That is why you don't need to explicitely specify a post ID

Comment: I see from WPSE that you've posted this question there. From that, I see you are using this in a shortcode. In that case, `echo $list;` should be `return $list;` as shortcode output should be returned, not echo'd